# How to read XML file which contains different symbols e.g. (←)

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, browser

Is it possible to replace symbols in XML file and read that XML file in C#? 
I have xml file which contains symbol like (←,↑) and I want to print that xml file on browser, but I had getting errors.

So is it possible to replace that symbols in xml and display valid xml file on browser?

Comment: Hi shas, because of I am not having enough reputation points I can't upload XML, Below is the problematic XML node;                                                                 <ObjectIdentifier value="7955">
   <Attribute name="ParentID" value="7948"/>
   <Attribute name="ModuleFullName" value="/CARTO III/Specification/moshe"/>
   <Attribute name="Object Heading" value=""/>
   <Attribute name="Object Text" value="←"/>
<Attribute name="is requirement" value="True"/>
  </ObjectIdentifier>

Comment: Corrupted files/documents aren't XML, despite the similarities to XML in this case. The real fix here is to insist that the person supplying you with the "XML" actually supplies XML, not a corrupt file. Help them to help themselves.

Comment: _"I want to print that xml file on browser, but I had getting errors."_ - read [ask] and provide the actual errors you get and show your research.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster...we have created a web service which returns output as XML on browser, first we have faced the issues for escaped characters(<,>,',",&) It was fixed successfully. But we are facing problems to fix issues of symbols in XML. I am getting error as "error on line 536 at column 41: Invalid character in attribute value".

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsXmlChar to find out the invalid XML characters and remove them.

Try out this

```
string sMyXMLContent = "<your xml string>";
var validXmlChars = sMyXMLContent.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray();
```

This will remove the invalid xml characters.